# Como puedo importar una clase en otra

Tags: c#

querria importar mi clase `Conexion.cs` en mi **Controlador** `Conductor` , hace tiempo que o toco `C#` y tonterias como estan me ponen la zancadilla.

Antes de nada explico lo que deseo hacer, simplemente para darle un poco mas de **sentido** a la pregunta:

Tengo mi clase `Conexion.cs` y mi clase `Conductor.cs` , en la segunda clase mencionada necesito hacer uso de la **conexion** para llevar a cabo las **funciones** que haran **consultas**. Dicho esto paso a mostrar lo que estoy haciendo:

**Conexion.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace Prueba.Conexion
{
    class Conexion{

        private string ConnectionString;
        private SqlConnection con;

        public Conexion() {
            this.ConnectionString = "";
            this.con = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
        }


        public void conectar() {
            this.con.Open();
        }

        public void desconectar() {
            this.con.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

**Conductor.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Conexion.Conexion;

namespace Prueba.Controladores
{
    class Conductor{


        private Conexion con;


        public Conductor() {

        }



    }
}
```

Esta segunda clase (`Conductor.cs`) me arroja **errores** porque asi no se **importa** la clase, es solo para que vean que estoy intentando.

Esta es la **estructura** de mis carpetas dentro del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**¿Como deberia de importar la clase `Conexion.cs` dentro de mi otra clase `Conductor.cs` de forma correcta?**

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que defini la clase como `public` para poder accederla desde otra clase

```
public class Conexion{

  //codigo

}
```

[Niveles de accesibilidad (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels)

Ademas ten en cuanta que puede sucederte lo mismo con `Conductor` si vas a usarla desde otro sitio

Tambien analiza el `using`, lo defines de forma incorrecta, este deberia ser el namespace

```
using Prueba.Conexion;
```

Comment: Pero aun asi no me detecta la clase **Conexion.cs** , laos ficheros estan 2 **carpetas** diferentes. Uno en una carpeta **Conexion** y el otro en una carpeta **Controladores**

Comment: He añadido la estrucutra de mis ficheros para que veas como lo tengo estrucutrado

Comment: El definir la carpeta solo afecta en la definicion del `namespace`, lo cual debes indicar en el `using` pero el public es neceario para hacer visible la class

Comment: Ya arregle el tema de import, simplemente lo pongo todo bajo el mismo `namespace` y listo, ahora estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de debugear el codigo. Pues tengo un error pero en VS no se exactamente como debuggear

Comment: No creo que la solucion fuera poner todo en el mismo namespace, sino mas bien definir bien el using, pero bueno. Respecto al depurar el codigo podrias estudiar algun tutorial que te ayude https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Te falta instanciar el objeto que quieres utilizar, en este caso el objeto Conexión.

Conexion.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace Prueba.Conexion
{
    class Conexion{

        private string ConnectionString;
        private SqlConnection con;

        public Conexion() {
            this.ConnectionString = "";
            this.con = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
        }


        public void conectar() {
            this.con.Open();
        }

        public void desconectar() {
            this.con.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Conductor.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Conexion.Conexion;

namespace Prueba.Controladores
{
    class Conductor{


        private Conexion con;


        public Conductor() {
            //te falta instanciar el objeto conexión para acceder a sus propiedades.
            this.con = new Conexion();

        }
    }
}
```